# Does max() still give the latest record when used with concatenate?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I concatenate 2 or more columns, will I still get the latest dates? Will these 2 statements always return the same date that's the latest order date?

```
select max(concat(order.orderdate,'|',order.quantity))
```

VS

```
select max(order.orderdate)
```

Comment: select concat(max(order.orderdate),'|',order.quantity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't be sure you will get the correct values using ``` max(concat())`` because you've now created a string so ``` max()` will operate on the entire string which follows alphanumeric rules rather than date rules.

To get information from the most recent row you can just use `top 1` + `order by` e.g.

```
declare @Order table (OrderDate date, Quantity int);

insert into @Order (OrderDate, Quantity)
values (current_timestamp, 1000)
  , (dateadd(day, -1, current_timestamp), 600)
  , (dateadd(day, -2, current_timestamp), 800);

select top 1 concat(format(OrderDate,'dd/MM/yyyy'),'|',format(Quantity,'#,###'))
from @Order
order by OrderDate desc;
```

A slightly more complex way of doing it (essential in some scenarios) is using `row_number()` to get the first row meeting your criteria e.g.

```
with cte as (
  select OrderDate, Quantity
    , row_number() over (order by OrderDate desc) rn
  -- change to dbo.[Order] for your real table
  from @Order
)
select concat(format(OrderDate,'dd/MM/yyyy'),'|',format(Quantity,'#,###'))
select top 1 concat(format(OrderDate,'dd/MM/yyyy'),'|',format(Quantity,'#,###'))
from cte
-- Comment out the following line to see all rows
from @Order
where rn = 1;
```

Note: `concat` works on strings, so rather than trusting the default conversion to a string I would recommend explicitly formatting the strings exactly how you want them as show in the query (change the format to suit your needs).

Answer (score 0):

No.  If you have values such as 9, 80, 700, then `max()` with a string argument versus number doesn't do what you expect.

However, the solution is simple, format the date as YYYYMMDD and format the number with leading zeros:

```
select max(concat(format(order.orderdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), '|', format(order.quantity, '000000')))
```