# Sort using max(concat(datetime+integer))

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some tables like these:

product

```
---------------------------
product_id  |  product_name
---------------------------
   1            p1
   2            p2
   3            p3
```

test

```
------------------------------------------------------
product_id  |  test_id  |  test_name   |  test_type    
------------------------------------------------------
   1            1          test1.1         duration
   2            2          test2.1         intrinsic
   3            3          test3.1         duration
   2            4          test2.2         scalability
   3            5          test3.2         intrinsic
   1            6          test1.2         duration
   2            7          test2.3         scalability
   2            8          test2.4         duration
   3            9          test3.3         intrinsic
```

test_function

```
------------------------------------------------------
func_id   |  test_id  |  test_start_date  |  func_type
------------------------------------------------------
   1            2          Jan 18, 2017       basic
   2            5          Jun 2, 2018        advanced
   3            7          Mar 9, 2011        basic
   4            3          May 20, 2021       basic
   5            1          Aug 1, 2020        advanced
   6            6          May 3, 1998        advanced
   7            8          Jul 17, 2017       basic
   8            4          Apr 3, 2016        basic
   9            9          Dec 21, 2019       basic
```

The desired result set: get each product's latest test_start_date and test_id by product_id. if more than 1 test has the same latest test_start_date, pick whichever.

```
------------------------------------------------
product_id  |  latest_test_start_date |  test_id  
------------------------------------------------
   1              Aug 1, 2020             1         
   2              Jul 17, 2018            8         
   3              May 20, 2021            3
```

I can't figure out how to get the `test_id` as a separate column so this is what I could come up with, however I can't get the latest `test_start_date` because `max(concat(tf.test_start_date, '|', tf.test_id))` is using alphabetic sort, not date sort. so I end up getting dates that are not the latest.

```
select p.product_id, max(concat(tf.test_start_date, '|', tf.test_id))
from product p
left join test t on p.product_id = t.product_id
left join test_function tf on t.test_id = tf.test_id
```

Any feedback or help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the actual type of the `test_start_date` column?  Is it text?

Comment: Why can't you use the answer to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163370/does-max-still-give-the-latest-record-when-used-with-concatenate) - it seems you're asking the same thing, just with a slightly different dataset.

Comment: umm, couldn't figure out how to apply the previous solution :<

Comment: data type of test_start_date is DATETIME

Comment: @edtopia using `row_number` you can pull any information you like from the row in question. The essentially what Georges answer below is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would join the three tables and rank them by **casting** the test_fn_date to a date followed by choosing the latest value arranged by row_number as follows..

here is a way to do this...

```
with data
  as (
select p.product_id
      ,tf.test_start_date
      ,tf.test_id
      ,cast(tf.test_start_date as date) as test_start_date_dt
      ,row_number() over(partition by p.product_id order by cast(tf.test_start_date as date) desc) as rnk
  from product p
  join test t
    on p.product_id=t.product_id
  join test_function tf
    on tf.test_id=t.test_id
     )
select *
  from data
 where rnk=1


+------------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+-----+
| product_id | test_start_date | test_id | test_start_date_dt | rnk |
+------------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+-----+
|          1 | Aug 1, 2020     |       1 | 2020-08-01         |   1 |
|          2 | Jul 17, 2017    |       8 | 2017-07-17         |   1 |
|          3 | May 20, 2021    |       3 | 2021-05-20         |   1 |
+------------+-----------------+---------+--------------------+-----+
```

db fiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=cd0ba78b6a9e6d66b667ddb6e83ca0e3

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a subquery for max start date goup by product

```
select p.product_id
, max(tf.test_start_date) max_date
, tf.test_id 
from product p
left join test t on p.product_id = t.product_id
left join test_function tf on t.test_id = tf.test_id
group by p.product_id

select t1.product_id, t1.max_date, 
from (
    select p.product_id
    , max(tf.test_start_date) max_date
    from product p
    left join test t on p.product_id = t.product_id
    left join test_function tf on t.test_id = tf.test_id
    group by p.product_id

) t1 
left join  test_function tf on t1.max_date = tf.test_start_date
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and fastest way to do this is using [analytical/window functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
with date_sort_num as (
  select p.product_id, 
         tf.test_start_date, 
         tf.test_id,
         row_number() over (partition by p.product_id order by tf.test_start_date desc) rn
    from product p
    left join test t on p.product_id = t.product_id
    left join test_function tf on t.test_id = tf.test_id
)
select product_id, test_start_date, test_id from date_sort_num where rn = 1
```

This returns one the latest `test_start_date` and its corresponding test_id. In this case if there's a tie for the latest `test_start_date` only one row will be selected arbitrarily. If you want to select all tied rows, then use `dense_rank` instead of `row_number`.